# How do you count nested blocks when they're yielded to a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, builder

I'm building an xml document without the use of the builder gem in Ruby. If I have code such as this:

```
def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
       tag_name = "<#{sym}/>"

      args.each do |hash|
         hash.each {|k,v| tag_name.insert(-3,(" #{k}=\"#{v}\"" )) }
      end

      if block
         tag_name = "<#{sym}>"+ block.call + "</#{sym}>
      end

      tag_name
  end


doc = XmlDocument.new(true)
doc.hello{doc.goodbye{doc.no}}
```

See how the #goodbye, and #no missing methods are passed as nested blocks? I need to be able to count them out so I can indent them in a builder pattern according to their order. How can I count them out to add indents? Is there a loop structure I can use? All the attempts I've used to count the blocks or block depth only  accoount for the outer one (XmlDocument#goodbye)

Comment: increase depth upon entering that `method_missing` and decrease when exiting. This way recursive structures will take care of indenting themselves.

Comment: You could also grab the depth of `Kernel.caller` when you start building and indent based on the difference as you go deeper.

Comment: Is there a method for grabbing those depths? Or manually increasing and decreasing that depth? I have done little to no metaprogramming, I'm not sure how that works

Comment: @SiouxsieAsylum: come on, this has nothing to do with metaprogramming. Just regular recursive programming. Try pretty-printing a simple binary tree first, to understand this technique.